# Malloc behaviour explanation

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I'm testing malloc to understand it behavior, and I have found something strange after some manipulation.

I have made 3 different tests with the same var.

First, I have alloc and free my 3 var one by one :

```
char  * a = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
printf("\na = %p\n", a);
free(a);
char  * b = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
printf("b = %p\n", b);
free(b);
char  * c = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
printf("c = %p\n\n", c);
free(c);
```

this display :

```
a = 0xd34010
b = 0xd34010
c = 0xd34010
```

Logical, it display the same address, memory space is recycled.

Then, I have malloc my 3 var, and then free :

```
printf("Alloc 3 times and then free :\n");
a = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
printf("\na = %p\n", a);
b = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
printf("b = %p\n", b);
c = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
printf("c = %p\n\n", c);
free(a); free(b); free(c);
```

It display me :

```
a = 0xd34010
b = 0xd34030
c = 0xd34050
```

`a` is logical because the last `c` variable had been free'ed, so the memory space is re-used. Addresses of `b` and `c` are logical too because `a` and `b` are not free'ed so addresses increase.

And now, It become really strange. 
I malloc a, then b, free a, malloc c and free b and c :

```
printf("Alloc, free, alloc :\n\n");
a = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
printf("a = %p\n", a);
b = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
printf("b = %p\n", b);
free(a);
c = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
printf("c = %p\n", c);
free(b); free(c);
```

the result is :

```
a = 0xd34050
b = 0xd34030
c = 0xd34050
```

My questions are : Why is `a` equal to 0xd34050 and not to 0xd34010 ? And why is the address of `b` lower than the address of `a` ?

Comment: Why do you care? Try to free them in the order `free(c); free(b); free(a);` in the second round.

Comment: feel that the last freed address is given to the next allocation of *same size*. of course it varies with implementation of `malloc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are performing these tests in one program and the `malloc` implementation you are using maintains a stack of some recently-freed blocks.

Thus, in the first test:

- The first `malloc`, needs new space, so 0xd34010 is given.
- 0xd34010 is freed.
- The second `malloc` is satisfied by providing the most recently freed block, 0xd34010.
- 0xd34010 is freed.
- The third `malloc` is satisfied by providing the most recently freed block, 0xd34010.
- 0xd34010 is freed.

Then, in the second test:

- The first `malloc` is satisfied by providing the most recently freed block, 0xd34010.
- The second `malloc` needs new space, so 0xd34030 is given.
- The third `malloc` needs new space, so 0xd34050 is given.
- 0xd34010 is freed.
- 0xd34030 is freed.
- 0xd34050 is freed.

Then, in the third test:

- The first `malloc` is satisfied by providing the most recently freed block, 0xd34050.
- The second `malloc` is satisfied by providing the most recently freed (and still free) block, 0xd34030.
- 0xd34050 is freed.
- The third `malloc` is satisfied by providing the most recently freed block, 0xd34050.
- 0xd34030 is freed.
- 0xd34050 is freed.

Of course, such behavior is not guaranteed by the C standard. This is merely a potential explanation of what you happen to observe in this particular instance.

Comment: This sounds very plausible. A linked list of freed blocks is very likely, and the easiest way to add and remove from a list is by pushing/popping as a stack.

Comment: It's true, but does it means that free do not really give the memory to the system after it execution ?

Comment: @JérémyPouyet: Most operating systems allocate memory to processes only in units called pages. Pages typically have sizes of 4096 bytes or more. It would not be inefficient for `malloc` and `free` to allocate and release a page every time a process allocates or releases 10 bytes. Instead, `malloc` allocates large amounts of space from the system, divides it up, and uses its own bookkeeping to keep track.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand, malloc call `sbrk()` to allocate a new page if necessary, such as free. So in some cases, if my program do not use a whole page, malloc will never call `sbrk()` and either free ?

Comment: @JérémyPouyet: I do not completely understand you question. However, consider what happens if your program allocates space A, `malloc` provides that space by using `sbrk`, then your program allocates space B, `malloc` provides that with `sbrk`, then your program frees A. Now `free` cannot release space with `sbrk`, because B is in the way. The `malloc` and `free` software must remember that A is free.

Comment: @JérémyPouyet: Also note that `malloc` is not required to use `sbrk`. It may get memory from the system in other ways, such as `mmap`.

Answer (score 4):

Because that's how memory allocation is implemented in the particular environment you are using.  That may sound flip, but the whole point of having such routines is so that they can take care of the bookkeeping for you; you've got more important things to do!

Comment: Your program should never care about the order of addresses returned by different calls to malloc.

Comment: @Jérémy Pouyet malloc has pretty complex functionality. You will not understand it in this way. You can download its source code and try to understand but even this will be difficult.

Comment: If you need to implement your proper malloc you can implement whatever way you want. The only thing that malloc needs to do is to allocate a bunch of memory. That's it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz he probably needs to implement `free` as well. :)

Comment: Yes, I have to implement free :) And for me, free do some sbrk(-size) to give the memory to the system, but after my test I'm not sure anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You do know that `printf` also calls `malloc` to allocate stream buffers? And those buffers are not necessarily cleared until you close `stdout`.

Try saving all your pointers separately before printing them.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be

> Why is a equal to 0xd34050 and not to 0xd34010 ?

Some other process in your machine already occupied the address 0xd34010, so your compiler gives you the next free memory.

And so far I know, depends on the compiler the memory may allocated in the ascending order or descending order. it is not necessarily to be in the ascending order.

Comment: These are _virtual_ memory addresses, other processes are irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar:Thanks for your comment. I meant some other process in the sense , the compiler may give that location to other programs that in need.

Comment: If you mean some other functions or data used in the same process, say so.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is machine dependent. Your Compiler's book keeping routine does it that way. It may be due to memory constraints given to it.
2. Since you used malloc, it uses Heap memory

Comment: He's not printing any stack addresses, all his addresses are in the heap. He's printing `a`, not `&a`.